# Chrome extension login best practices

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension popup and need login. For now, I will make my own authentication with a username and password, but what are best practices within an extension?

Here are my thoughts:

- I will make the login against a remote server using a post.
- Get a token back which I will keep in local storage for an amount of time.
- The popup should also have a register inside it

Is it good to keep it all inside the extension? This is where I want my users to be, and not in some website to register and so on.

The change from login to "home page" or the registration page, should this be done with messaging?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should always use [OAuth 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0) for authentication within extensions. Never pass the username/password because an attacker can simply steal such information.

An example from Chromium regarding OAuth in extensions is *[Tutorial: OAuth](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth)*.

Additionally, there's an experimental API available for OAuth 2.0, which is supposed to make the whole process a little easier. There's a comprehensive blog post, *[OAuth 2.0 from Chrome Extensions](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions)*.

Comment: Rasmus, I updated my answer with the tutorial on how to implement it client side.

Comment: Is this true? Lastpass allows you to log in inside the popup and they seem secure...

Comment: is it still working ? I heard there's some part of deprecated one?

Comment: Assuming you only send the username/password over an SSL encrypted connection I don't see what kind of attack oauth protects against that username/password doesn't.  Either way you store a secret in the broswer's local storage whose theft allows an attacker to impersonate the user and the SSL cert & encryption protects against sniffing/MITM.