# Chrome extensions login (Basic authentication)

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-chrome-extension, basic-authentication

I am developing chrome extension where I need to login to one site which uses HTTP Basic Authentication. I'm thinking about something like, when user opens up chrome application, he can log in via pop-up and stays logged in the whole time chrome application is running (on every tab).

So I guess, ext. needs to take name/pass from popup, then sends them to background page (because background page is running the whole time) and log in there. 
Are there any *best practices/advices* of login via Basic Authentication? How to make something like "session"? Where should I correctly place loggin phase?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension login best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217137/chrome-extension-login-best-practices)