# What is the most secure way of using user credentials inside a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension

I'm aware of the following ..

- Saving them using `Storage` api is not secure, since they are openly accessible on disk
- Could encrypt them before saving to `Storage`, but decrypt mechanism is well known
- Credentials are only secure if laptop is powered off :)

I need the username and password since I make a login request to my web service inside my `background.js` script once loaded:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
```

Would the most secure method be, provide a UI which does not persist the credentials?

When form submitted I make the login request using provided username and password. So every-time browser is loaded, user would be required to re-enter the credentials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension login best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217137/chrome-extension-login-best-practices)

Comment: There's an experimental API to the browser's saved passwords: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Credential_Management_API. But until that becomes more mature, you'd probably want to prompt the user for their username and password, just like most websites do.