# Login operation through extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, passwords, firefox-addon

Most of the password managers have a web extension. The extension fetches the login details from a desktop application(such as in Dashlane) or from a vault associated within the browser(such as in LastPass). These extensions then fill in the login form with the corresponding details. However, there is always a  possibility to hack the credentials from the login form through other means.

Hence, I would like to know the possibility of an extension performing a direct login into the application without filling the form. That is, say I build an extension and a password manager. My extension should fetch the login details from the password manager and perform a login operation on its own without having the need to fill in the login form of the web page. In this case, the probability of the credentials being stolen is not completely eradicated, but however is reduced.

It would be really helpful if I could get some thoughts on this.

Comment: What you are essentially looking for is a direct POST request. However, that may not work in cases where a captcha is required.

Comment: @Manos Forsaken Thanks for the comment. But not most of the websites employ captcha. Are there any other ways this can be achieved.

Comment: You may want to check this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217137/chrome-extension-login-best-practices) wherein it was suggested that you should always use [OAuth 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0) for authentication and to never pass the username/password because an attacker can simply steal such information. For more information, see [Tutorial: OAuth](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has some flaws.  Think a bit about the following.

Form auto-fill is easy to be handled by an extension, as you only need to detect a form element, associated with a domain specific page that you keep track of.  If the form is taken out of the equation, the extension instead of auto-filling the form should auto-post the data to the service controller that serves the login form.  In order to do that, you'll need to keep track of all POST URLs associated with the login forms you manage (after detecting them of course).

Let's assume that you somehow keep track of form POST endpoints.  Then you will need to actually POST the data to the service in order to authenticate the user.  Since the extension - as opposed to the login form - doesn't conform to the same origin policy, then you will need to add some CORS in order to be able to perform the requests.  But that of course is easy within the extension.

Which brings us to the next concern.  Login form requests are meant to be stateful and therefore a successful login response sets a cookie on the client which is used for session management.  Since an extension is operating in a sand-boxed environment it cannot modify cookies from 3rd party domains.

Long story short.  Your idea might sound cool in that it eliminates one step in the process, but my rule of thumb is that if a certain paradigm has been around for too long, then there must be more than one good reasons behind that.