# Best practice for authentication within extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a bookmark extension which communicate with my own web app. The user can install the extension on browser like Firefox and login. Currently I send the data per ajax to the server and check. I know this is not the secure way. I read about OAuth2, but this is only if I need data from a third part. Is there a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217137/chrome-extension-login-best-practices), you should always use `OAuth 2.0` for authentication within extensions. You may check this [article](https://www.informationsecuritybuzz.com/articles/security-and-privacy-best-practices-on-building-a-chrome-extension/) for the ***Security and Privacy: Best Practices on Building a Chrome Extension***.