# Chrome Extension identity: OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad request'

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I followed https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth exactly step by step but I am stuck at

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth#identity_permission

where  after I execute my extension, instead of getting the token, I get the error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.getAuthToken: 
OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'bad request'
```

Please suggest what is the possible cause of this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244710

Comment: i think i got the same case as yours....

Comment: are you adding `key` to manifest.json?
this contains public key.

Comment: Thank you stack overflow gods! This is exactly what I needed after hours of searching the internet!

Answer (score 39):

## tl;dr

Update the scopes to the following if its empty,

```
 "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "yourExtensionOAuthClientIDWillGoHere.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]
  }
```

---

People who were following the tutorial on [OAuth2: Authenticate Users with Google](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tut_oauth)

If you've landed into this problem, it is probably because it's 2020 and the documentation isn't updated.

The tutorial asks you to,

> Include the "oauth2" field in the extension manifest. Place the generated OAuth client ID under "client_id". Include an empty string in "scopes" for now.
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "OAuth Tutorial FriendBlock",
>   ...
>   "oauth2": {
>     "client_id": "yourExtensionOAuthClientIDWillGoHere.apps.googleusercontent.com",
>     "scopes":[""]
>   },
>   ...
> }
> ```

but never updates it before calling the identity API call to fetch the token.

Updating the scopes, with the following should fix the issue,

```
"scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Still doesn't work for me (and actually this was working at some point in the last few years). I get `OAuth2 request failed: Connection failed`

Comment: Thank you very much. i was going crazy over this

Comment: The official documentation shows an empty string inside scopes, Google sucks even at documentation https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/integrate/oauth

Answer (score 14):

I think that's because the scope is empty. I was like you follow the article, but found the problem is from the scope area.

Comment: For those who are wondering, the "scopes" is the one in the "manifest.json" > "oauth2" > "scopes"

Comment: For those wondering what to put into scopes - just scroll down the google documentation page to find the example

Comment: Then what do I do? What do i do with the scope? The guide says to leave it empty but clearly that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @nilesh How exactly did you fix the issue? My scope is still empty and thus it doesnt work.

Comment: @nilesh You need to set a scope.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the scope as suggested but the problem still persisted. Then I tried not only to reload the extension but also tried to update it and it worked in the end (errors next to Remove button went away and I am able to authenticate).

Honestly, I am not sure if it is the Update that did the magic or change the empty Scope that did the magic but here is an answer from a 2020 July user who got it working. :)

(PS, if you don't have that many Google friends, or your friends who don't bother to have image, likely your code will fail with `data.photos[0].url` in the next step, you just need to take care of that)

[image]
[image]