# Best practice for implementing a login within a Chrome extension

Tags: security, authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to find the best way to incorporate a login form inside my extension's popup page just like Passbolt password manager.

I have endlessly searched for solutions and examples only to find some that do not go into much detail (like OAuth). Furthermore, I am trying to completely avoid having to prompt a popup login page to do the job.

Is there any way to securely send over the credentials to my API's controller directly from the extension?

Any examples or resources would be very helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension login best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217137/chrome-extension-login-best-practices)

Comment: @CameronDowner Thanks but unfortunately no. There aren't enough answers on that post that specifically answer mine. Is there a secure way to send credentials over to my api? Somehow I cannot find any example yet many extensions implement this.

Comment: You could probably do a simple HTTPS call with the credentials for a session id/token, but it's recommended you complete an OAuth flow to get a token because this is the most secure option.